# How to get the time stamp from the output and compare with Current time stamp

Tags: shell, date, timestamp, compare, ls

I am printing the list of file present in a directory in linux server, and from the output i need to pick only the timestamp and compare it with current system timestamp.How to achieve this using shell. I am not sure how to pick only part of the string which contains the date modified from the output.
 **Command Used:**

```
ls -lart *.jar
```

**Actual output:**

```
-rx-r--r-- jenkins jenkins 4095 sep 24 05:06 services.jar
-rx-r--r-- jenkins jenkins 4095 sep 24 05:06 snapshots.jar
```

**Expected output:**

```
sep 24 05:06
```

I need to compare the timestamp output with current timestamp. Please help on the actual command. TIA

Comment: If you want to do timestamp comparisons against the current time, I recommend using the stat(1) and date(1) commands.

Comment: You'll also want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs